# Will a table created using Postgres DDL be converted to other DB DDL in Liquibase?

Tags: oracle, postgresql, liquibase

I created a DDL like below using Liquibase in my project:

```
CREATE TABLE customer_payload
(
    id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    customer_name varchar(150) NOT NULL,
    source_dt date NOT NULL,
    uuid    varchar(150) NOT NULL,
    status smallint,
    payload text NOT NULL,
    created timestamp default now(),
    last_updated timestamp
)
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
);
```

At that time I was unaware of Liquibase schema types.

If tomorrow lets say we move to MySql or Oracle, will Postgres types like '**BIGSERIAL**' and '**text**'
be automatically converted to Oracle or MySql corresponding type or do I need to define there in postgre types i.e. 'clob' for text and whatever is the equivalent of BigSerial in liquibase?

In short, even if the DDL is not defined in native liquibase format, can it still map rows between different databases it supports?

Comment: Liquibase can only adapt to the target DBMS if you use its XML format for the changelogs. If you run SQL scripts, there is nothing Liquibase cando